# Multi slot CPU mainboard running Linux

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, xeon

Soon we will receive a 2-CPU mainboard with 2 Quad-Core Xeons on it. We have also a GNU system with Linux kernel (preconfigured). Currently, this Linux runs on a multi-core 1-CPU (Quad Core).

My question is if I will disable in BIOS one of the Xeons, will current Linux run on only one CPU? Will I need to change Linux configuration settings?

Here is important config settings:

```
CONFIG_NUMA=y
CONFIG_K8_NUMA=y
CONFIG_X86_64_ACPI_NUMA=y
CONFIG_NUMA_EMU=y
CONFIG_ACPI_NUMA=y
# CONFIG_X86_VSMP is not set
CONFIG_SMP=y
CONFIG_SUSPEND_SMP=y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will work...but I have to ask the question...why would you do this?

Comment: Thanks! This board is for server prototype. First we have to test our system on a new Xeon CPU, if it is enough CPU Performance then we will stay with cheaper 1-CPU(4Cores) on board solution for mass-production. If more performance will be required, then we will utilize 8 cores (2CPUx4Cores).

Comment: Can you also please specify why it will work? Maybe a link?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? As far as the OS is concerned, unless you are talking about a really large number of cores like 64 or more, 1-core or 8-core will work, with only the difference in performance. An SMP enabled Linux kernel will still work on 1-core, just without the multi-core magic.

Answer (score 0):

A single CPU is just a special case of multiple CPUs, so the same code will work just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here. Care to clarify?

Comment: Literally, the kernel boots up on the first CPU and enumerates other CPUs and boots them if it finds them installed and working. If there is only 1 cpu then it carries on just fine.